# .htaccess, redirect website but with exceptions

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am redirecting an entire website, with a few exceptions. I have the following rules and conditions in place:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^loans\.myoldwebsite\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^client\.myoldwebsite\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(client|loans)\.myoldwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewwebsite.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

But I also need to make sure that `http://www.myoldwebsite.com/getLead.php` is ignored as well, so it doesn't get redirected.

Comment: Normally you would put a condition like `RewriteCond !-f` which means that the rule only applies if the file doesn't exist. So if you are loading a file that exists directly the rewrite rule doesn't apply. This is more of a blanket solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple `RewriteCond`s:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(client|loans)\.myoldwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/getLead.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewwebsite.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```